# Native HTML5 Drag and Drop in Mobile Safari (iPad, iPod, iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, drag-and-drop, mobile-safari

I've successfully implemented **native HTML5 Drag and Drop** for **moving HTML elements inside a page** (just, say, a div from one place to another, nothing related to interacting with the host OS' files whatsoever). This works fine in Chrome and Safari on a PC but I can't start a drag operation in my iPad's Safari.

I've found this so far:

> Using Drag and Drop From JavaScript
>
> Safari, Dashboard, and WebKit-based
>   applications include support for
>   customizing the behavior of drag and
>   drop operations within your HTML
>   pages.
>
> Note: This technology is supported
>   only on desktop versions of Safari.
>   For iPhone OS, use DOM Touch,
>   described in Handling Events (part of
>   Safari Web Content Guide) and Safari
>   DOM Additions Reference.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/DragAndDrop.html). But it's outdated (2009-06-08).

Doe's anyone know if it is possible to use **native** HTML5 in Mobile Safari? (I don't want javascript-framework like solutions like jQuery UI).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've just been trying to get native drag&drop working in ios safari (ipad pro with 14.0.1), and I'm updating this answer as it kept coming up as my first google result (and no other q&a seems to be up to date).

Following https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html
I have found native html5 drag&drop now works in safari, with a few specific notes;

- You MUST set some data in OnDragStart's event; (the effect settings seem to be optional) `Event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'hello');`
- you MUST `Event.preventDefault();` in `OnDrop` otherwise safari will load the data you added (unless that's your intention)
- `OnDragOver` event handler needs `Event.preventDefault();` otherwise drop fails (unless intended, as docuemnted)
- On ios safari, if you set `OnDragStart`'s `Event.dataTransfer.dropEffect='copy'` and in `OnDragOver`'s `Event.dataTransfer.dropEffect='link'` the drop fails (no `OnDrop()`); Seems to be the only combination that fails

I thought you required

- CSS `-webkit-user-drag: Element;` and `-webkit-user-drop: element;
  or if you prefer

```
Element.style.setProperty('webkitUserDrag','element');
Element.style.setProperty('webkitUserDrop','element');
```

but it seems just the usual `draggable` attribute is enough
`Element.setAttribute('draggable',true);`

This seems to be the bare minimum to drag & drop an element

```
        Element.setAttribute('draggable',true);
        
        function OnDragOver(Event)
        {
            Element.setAttribute('DragOver',true);
            Event.stopPropagation();    //  let child accept and don't pass up to parent element
            Event.preventDefault();     //  ios to accept drop
            Event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';//   move has no icon? adding copy shows +
        }
        function OnDragLeave(Event)
        {
            Element.removeAttribute('DragOver');
        }
        function OnDrop(Event)
        {
            Element.removeAttribute('DragOver');
            Event.preventDefault();     //  dont let page attempt to load our data
            Event.stopPropagation();
        }
        function OnDragStart(Event)
        {
            Event.stopPropagation(); // let child take the drag
            Event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
            Event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'hello');
        }
        Element.addEventListener('dragstart',OnDragStart);
        Element.addEventListener('drop',OnDrop);
        Element.addEventListener('dragover',OnDragOver);
        Element.addEventListener('dragleave',OnDragLeave);
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized all that was missing in my case was `Event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'hello')`.

Answer (score 3):

Touch events do work now on Safari too (including Mobile). This article has nice code snippets that you can start from:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/