# React to HTML5 mouse events on FireFox and iPod (Safari?)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll, 2d

I am updating my [scrolling game engine](http://sgdk2.sf.net/) to output HTML5 code for the scrolling maps it generates, so that it can be used not only as a (somewhat-platform-specific) complete game creator, but also as a cross-platform HTML5 scrolling map editor.  I got past the challenge of supporting the graphic tinting as described in my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785072/modulate-colors-with-drawimage-on-html5-canvas/7785405#7785405). And I have a nice sample running at http://sgdk2.enigmadream.com/ben/.  However I have noticed that the mouse interaction for scrolling the map does not work on FireFox or on an iPod.  It looks like iPod may use different events (ontouch etc) according to [Native HTML5 Drag and Drop in Mobile Safari (iPad, iPod, iPhone)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600950/native-html5-drag-and-drop-in-mobile-safari-ipad-ipod-iphone).  And that doesn't explain why FireFox wouldn't react.  Isn't there a more universal way to support mouse *or* touch interaction?  Do the touch events also work for mouse, or are they specific to touch?  How would you recommend interacting with this scrolling map in the most cross-platform compatible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to correctly retrieve your srcElement

```
var srcEl = e.srcElement? e.srcElement : e.target;
```

try it

P.S.: see [targets](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_events.html#targets)

Comment: also check your event:  e= e || window.event;

Comment: I've updated the code, and it still doesn't seem to be working in FireFox.

Comment: I think your script generally is written without cross browser compatibility, e.g. for making events work in other browsers than IE you need to use  addEventListener instead of assigning a function to element.onEventName property, and so on.. why you do not use some js framework e.g. jQuery? it does take care of browser compatibility for you

Comment: or you are using offsetX - this wont work in FF either, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#offsetX

Comment: Since this code is being generated, it seems clumsy to require a third party framework to make it work, especially for such a small thing as hooking up these few events.  I don't need a whole framework for that.  I just need to do it in a cross-platform-compatible way.  It works on both IE and Chrome, so I thought I was close.  But it's been a long time since I had to get into the browser wars so I've probably forgotten (or never learned) many of the significant differences between browsers.

Comment: unfortunately it's still an issue :(

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html I shouldn't need to use addEventListener for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Once I switched to clientX and clientY instead of offsetX and offsetY, things started working in FireFox.