# drag and drop for mobile devices using jquery mobile touchmove event

Tags: jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop, touch

I am trying to implement drag and drop functionality for iPad using jquery mobile using touchmove event. Before doing this I read kind of a lot of questions here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172100/html-drag-and-drop-on-mobile-devices), which actually looks for a suitable framework, which I am not looking into. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600950/native-html5-drag-and-drop-in-mobile-safari-ipad-ipod-iphone), [this](http://www.devinrolsen.com/basic-jquery-touchmove-event-setup/) and [this](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/) which helps with how drag and drop can be imlemented.

My code looks as follows (here is only my relevant html/js, the full relevant code can be found in fiddle).

**HTML**

```
<span class="square"> 1 </span>
<span class="square-big"> 1 </span>
```

**JS**

```
$('.square').on('touchmove',function(e){
    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
    var elm = $(this).offset();
    $(this).addClass('selected').css({
        left: touch.screenX - elm.left,
        top: touch.screenY - elm.top
    });
    $('.square-big').addClass('selected');
}).on('touchend', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('.square-big').removeClass('selected');
});
```

My code partially works. By this I mean, that the element is moving but way it moves is really ugly and it is kind of far away from the finger. It is also shaking.

This is because I calculate wrongly my left and top. But I can not get how exactly I need to calculate them. Any ideas would be appreciated.

You can try my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xbGeS/2/), but for some reason I can not correctly get rid of screen move in jsfiddle, so it is better to copy the whole code and to [run it through localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3132105/1090562).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this yourself? I had similar issues with drag and drop in IE using mouse events...I really think it was due to IE rendering. Though someone suggested to use javascript because it is slightly faster than jquery.

Comment: @t1nr2y no, I have not found. Regarding your last sentence the shaking is not due to performance problems, so there will be no difference whether I use jquery or js.

Comment: OK, well if I find something to help-I'll come back and post a link.