# React draggable events don't work in mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag, drop

My code in React with onDrag events works well in desktop, but in mobile versions it doesn't. I don't know if is necessary another option in mobile

This is the code I'm trying (using Chrome devtools for drag&drop as mobile)

```
const Board = () => {
  const onDragHandler = e => {
    console.log('This is dragging')
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        draggable
        className="box"
        onDragStart={onDragHandler}
      ></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837500/drag-and-drop-with-touch-support-for-react-js. I've run into the same issue and it looks like using https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd is the best option here